# Meaning of grey and yellow/brown colors of buildings in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, color

I'm wondering what the difference beween those yellowish and the grey buildings is in Google Maps.
I marked a few of the yellowish building as an example in the picture below.
[image: Yellowish buildings on Google Maps]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Orange buildings are "interesting", according to Google. In my experience with areas that I am familiar with, these are buildings that are "popular", as likely determined by how many people visit, check in there, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a recent blog post from Google with some information on this: https://maps.googleblog.com/2016/07/discover-action-around-you-with-updated.html

> We determine “areas of interest” [orange/yellow areas] with an algorithmic process that allows us to highlight the areas with the highest concentration of restaurants, bars and shops. In high-density areas like NYC, we use a human touch to make sure we’re showing the most active areas.

Answer (score 5):

Orange buildings represent areas of interest determined by an algorithm.

Comment: Could you add a source or reference for this statement?

Answer (score 4):

According to this [Google Maps Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/eLJKHp81WKo) where an answer has been marked by a Google Maps Community Manager:

- White roads = Normal streets
- Yellow roads = Main streets/roads
- Orange roads = Highways
- Very light gray = Normal areas (houses, buildings, etc)
- Green = Parks
- Light green = Forests
- Light brown = Universities
- Grey = Factories, harbours and other heavy duty areas.
- Ligh red = Hospitals

Comment: Note: the referenced answer is from 2011 and may be outdated.

Comment: In terms of actual correlation with what's on the ground, "green = there might be something park-like in this general area".  Google is spectacularly bad at mapping the larger parks around me.

Comment: @Mark - Yes, now that you mention it, I have noticed something similar in areas around me too...

Answer (score 0):

I live at an Apartment complex, having three main buildings. One of them is yellowed, the others are Grey. Make some sense of that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/226253)